# keyboard buffer(taking strings as input)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

when we hit many enter key, then why '/0' is not stored in the string.i.e. why enter key does not remain in keyboard buffer?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("================================");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            String s1=sc.next();
            System.out.printf("%s",s1);//on pressing enter key many time also it does not remain in buffer. why? why? why?
        }
        System.out.println("================================");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the scanner object uses delimiter to filter the input. There is default delimiter `\p{javaWhitespace}+` you can see it with `System.out.println(sc.delimiter());`. That is a regular expression that basically  says ignore all empty or blank lines. When you press enter you are passing empty lines which get ignored.

To read the line no matter what it is use `sc.nextLine();`

Other option is to use `sc.next(pattern);`, but I can see the point in that.

You can read more about the Scanner [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: then in following program why enter key is not removed.import java.util.Scanner;
public class sum {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
  int a;
  String b;
  
  a=obj.nextInt();
  b=obj.nextLine();
  System.out.println("hello");
  System.out.println(b); // enter key is taken as input directly for string so string will be empty
  System.out.println(a);
  

 }

}

Comment: Because next line (as the name suggests ) has delimiter regex which searches for new line symbol, it probably uses next(pattern) internally to catch all possible end of input symbols, but that just guesing